# How to delete multiple files that is created or owned by 'root'

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I want to clear all files in my `/tmp` that is created by `root` user.

```
jenkins@hudson:/tmp$ ls -la | grep root
drwxrwxrwt 14 root    root     876544 Jan  7 11:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 root    root       4096 Jan  6 16:20 ..
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root       4096 Nov 16 11:02 .ICE-unix
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root       4096 Nov 16 11:02 .X11-unix
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root        856 Jan  6 16:27 deliveryOrderCSVDataGeneratorTest.2047035348.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root          0 Jan  6 16:18 dome1_goods_return_note_item_GRN-00001.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root        424 Jan  6 16:18 dome_credit_note_20160106-1618.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root        319 Jan  6 16:18 dome_credit_note_items_20160106-1618.csv
```

I just want to remove all files with the extension of `.csv` and `.dbf` files since they're failing my php unit testing.

Those files were created in `/tmp` folder by `root` because I once accidentally ran the unit testing with `sudo` before.

So, I am wondering how I can delete all those *files* and to **avoid** *folders (like '.' and '..')* that is created or owned by `root`?

*Note: I have sudo access. I am just still newb in ubuntu terminal commands.*

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't delete random files owned by root without knowing what they are and the impact of deleting them.

The csv files owned by root can be removed with:-

`/bin/rm $(find /tmp/*.csv -user root -print)`

The two dot files .ICE-unix and .X11-unix will likely cause problems for graphical applications running under X or VNC if you delete them.

It looks like you're running some kind of Ubuntu server, so the dot files may be hanging around from an old VNC server which has long since been shutdown. If that's the case you can just remove them by name `rm /tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/.ICE-unix`.

Comment: Hi popey, `rm /tmp/*.csv` will delete all csv files for all users. I just want to delete all `.csv` and `.dbf` files that is owned or created by root users.

Comment: gotcha, thought it was a one off, but you want to do it more than once, I've edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Yayy, Thank you so much.. This solution works for me. Sorry for my bad explaination btw.